# Delete from where count greater than 1, but keep a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this (SQL2008):

```
id   url                  updated
1    http://url1.com      null
2    http://url2.com      <datetime>
3    http://url1.com      <datetime>
```

I want to delete ONE of the url1.com records (preferably where updated is not null, but its fine if it doesnt work that way)

I have this query, which deletes all the duplicates - but doesn't keep a record (which is where i'm confused):

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE url IN (
    SELECT url
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY url
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

How do I limit the delete? Result would ideally be:

```
id   url                  updated
1    http://url1.com      null
2    http://url2.com      <datetime>
```

Right now it ends up like:

```
id   url                  updated
2    http://url2.com      <datetime>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `SQL2008` is SQL Server 2008, then you can do this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY url
                                    ORDER BY updated DESC)
    FROM [table]
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: What is this sorcery! Just flipped the order by and it was what I was looking for. Where can I learn more about this query?

Comment: Glad it worked. the `CTE` (common table expression) isn't actually necessary, you could as well use a derived table, but I think that this code is far cleaner. `ROW_NUMBER()` is a windowing analytical function, and they are very useful for a lot of things, so it's worth to look them up

Comment: @Lamak, you don't need the * in the CTE

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY url
     )
```